# Oracle 11g and 12c together

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g, oracle12c

I'm trying to use oracle 11g and 12c tools on the same machine.

**Scenario:**

1 - I'm developing a winforms app using Oracle.DataAccess from 11g

2 - I'm developing a web API with Entity Framework using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess from 12c

3 - I'm support a third party app that depends on oracle client 11g

**Situation:**

I manage to run and deploy the winforms app without oracle client installation, after that I started to develop the web API, so I installed ODT with ODAC121024 (including oracle client from 12c), and both work fine.

Then I had to support the third party app that needs oracle client from 11g, but I couldn't run the app because I did not had oracle client 11g, so I deinstall every thing on mine machine and installed the full oracle 11g.

Now the winforms app and the third party add works fine, but I couldn't make the web API to work.

I installed the nuget packages `oracle.manageddataaccess` and `oracle.manageddataaccess.entityframework`. But I'm getting the follow error on one of the projects of my solution (with 5 projects):

> Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

This error occur on the `.edmx` file of my data model project.

I can't create another `.edmx` file as well because the oracle data provider does not show up on Visual Studio (2013).

For this to work I have to install ODT with ODAC121024, but I this will mess up the third party app access.

The question is: how to use ODAC 12c without installing the client?

Thanks.